# SoftAssert fails all my test methods after calling SoftAssertobj.assertAll() function

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, assertion

I am automating a website and i'm using soft assert for failing my testcases. But now I am getting failure reports for all the testmethods which comes after a test method that failed in a particular scenario. Given below is the sample code

```
    //Function Call 

    commFunction.backnavigation(driver, props,"Item",ExcelResult_Field, className,"CustomerPricing");

//Function Declaration

    public void backnavigation(WebDriver driver, Properties props,
            String MenuName, boolean TestStatus, String className,
            String MethodName) throws InterruptedException,
            EncryptedDocumentException, InvalidFormatException, IOException {



        Boolean bool_backButton = ValidationHelper.isElementPresent(driver,
                By.xpath(LocatorModule(props, "BackNavigationButton")));

        if (bool_backButton.equals(true)) {
            ExecutionHelper.ElementTobeClicked_Xpath(driver,
                    By.xpath(LocatorModule(props, "BackNavigationButton")));

          ListClassView = ExecutionHelper
                    .waitForElementVisible(
                            driver,
                            By.xpath("//ul[@id='settings_menu']//li/a[text()='"
                                    + MenuName
                                    + "']/ancestor::li/following-sibling::li[1]/ul/li"));

            if (ListClassView.equals(true)) {
                 writeResulttoExcel(TestStatus, className,
                        MethodName);
                  if(TestStatus!=true)
                  {
                        // softAssert.assertEquals(false, true,"TEST STATUS Fail--assert fail"); 
                      softAssert.fail("TEST STATUS Fail--assert fail");
                  }
            }

            else {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                driver.findElement(
                        By.xpath(".//*[@id='settings_menu']/li[@class='left width_fluid']/a[text()='"
                                + MenuName + "']")).click();
                 writeResulttoExcel(false, className, MethodName);
                 //softAssert.assertEquals(false, true,"ListClassView FALSE--assert fail"); 
                   softAssert.fail("ListClassView FALSE--assert fail");
                 Thread.sleep(2000);
            }

            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }

        else {
            driver.navigate().back();
            Boolean ListClassView = ExecutionHelper
                    .waitForElementVisible(
                            driver,
                            By.xpath("//ul[@id='settings_menu']//li/a[text()='"
                                    + MenuName
                                    + "']/ancestor::li/following-sibling::li[1]/ul/li"));
            if (ListClassView.equals(true))
            {
                 writeResulttoExcel(false, className, MethodName);
                // softAssert.assertEquals(false, true,"BACK BUTTON FALSE LIST VIEW AVAILABLE--assert fail");

                   softAssert.fail("BACK BUTTON FALSE LIST VIEW AVAILABLE--assert fail");

            }

            else {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                driver.findElement(
                        By.xpath(".//*[@id='settings_menu']/li[@class='left width_fluid']/a[text()='"
                                + MenuName + "']")).click();
                 writeResulttoExcel(false, className, MethodName);
            //   softAssert.assertEquals(false, true,"BACK BUTTON FALSE LIST VIEW NOT AVAILABLE--assert fail"); 
                 softAssert.fail("BACK BUTTON FALSE LIST VIEW NOT AVAILABLE--assert fail");

            }

            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }
       softAssert.assertAll();
    }
```

Here Method 1 should fail in my actual scenario and Method 2 should pass. But after calling softAssert.assertAll(); both Method 1 & 2 is failing. Attaching the TestNG report for the scenario. The Tests After customer pricing should fail but report shows all the test method got failed.What change should be applied to resolve this.?

[TestNG Report Image File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1SB0.png)

Comment: paste your actual code.  If you are calling the same function, then both will fail.  also asserttrue takes just one argument..

Comment: @niharika_neo  Updated the actual code.Please have a look into that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is your @Test method in provided code? are you calling your pre-defined backnavigation method in @Test? Where did you created softAssert object? below simple example will helps you.

```
  public class SoftAsert
{
@Test
public void test()
{
    SoftAssert asert=new SoftAssert();
    asert.assertEquals(false, true,"failed");
    asert.assertEquals(0, 1,"brokedown");
    asert.assertAll();
}
}
```

Please initiate the SoftAssert object in @Test it self and on end of @Test use assertAll, so that it will provide failure details of that particular Test only.

Thank You,
Murali

Answer (score 0):

You Need to declare and initialize SoftAssert object in each @Test. However if wish to use HardAssert then no need to declare and initialize HardAssert in each @Test. Just declare and initialize Assert globally(once per test class).